# Android application using worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Tool which code is developed using "C" Language. Now i am developing Android application using worklight.I need to connect to the CICS server using TCP/IP. Here my question is, do we have any TCP/IP functionality in java script or some other language so that i can use that to develop android application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that you haven't done much research before posting a question.  Most every language has some ability to do TCP/IP networking.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface it sounds like that you need to connect to a Server.

In Worklight, in order to connect to a server and retrieve information from it - you use Adapters. In your case, it sounds like you need to use the HTTP adapter.

So you need to go ahead and read about Adapters in general, and then about HTTP adapters.

- Developer Center: [Adapters Overview](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/)
- Developer Center: [HTTP adapters](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/http-adapter-communicating-http-back-end-systems/)
- Knowledge Center: [Developing the server side of a MobileFirst application](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_DevelopingTheServer-sideOfAnIBMWorklightApplication.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me explain my requirement in simple way. I need to connect to the mainframe server using TCP/IP . Currently i am using the Worklight tool to develop the android mobile app. I hope this give you more clear about my requiremnt. Please suggest me on this

Comment: My answer is the same. You need to use an HTTP adapter.

Comment: Thanks Idan Adar.. One more question is,Currently we have c language code which is connecting to mainframe sever using TCP/IP concept by sending sockets. Here my concern is,do we have sockets concept in HTTP Adapter?

Comment: You could probably write a Java class.